# Connected to specific Wifi but "no internet" (Win 10)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet

I'm experiencing a really weird behaviour of my connection to the wifi in my office.
Wifi connection is working fine everywhere (at home, at other offices, ...)

In one specific co-working office my notebook can not access the internet through the office wifi. I can connect to the wifi and I can use Slack and if already running, a Google-Meet session works without any fault if I connect to this wifi. I also can ping ip adresses and resolve domains.

I figured out it seems the request is submitted but every new connection does not respond.
Currently I am tunneling the wifi through my phone via USB cable to the laptop (yes, this works).
So my phones and even my MacBook can connect and work with this wifi. Also no other colleague here has such trouble.

System: Win 10 Pro on a Dell XPS 15

How to get more information from my system to debug this situation?

Comment: Run TCP/IP Reset and restart when complete.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer

Comment: Followed your instructions, but nothing changed in the behaviour

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run both:  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth followed by  SFC /SCANNOW.   Restart and test.  If that does not work, run a Windows 10 Repair Install:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reset your Wi-Fi network.

Go to Settings > Update and security > Troubleshoot and select Network adapter troubleshooter.

Check if the network adapter has faulty or outdated drivers. If that's the case, call manufacturer or visit their website to get new drivers.

Comment: everything is up to date